# Render text in sql field as variable

Tags: php, html

Does anyone know how to render the data store in php to read as an indication of variable rather than text?

Let say I have an html input field:

```
<input name="location" type="text"/>
```

In the input field I type in $address. This string is stored in a sql field named "location".

In php, I have:

```
    $address = "123 Magic Blvd";
    $sql = $DB_CON_C->prepare("SELECT * FROM places WHERE number=:number");
           $sql->bindValue(':number', $number, PDO::PARAM_STR);
           $sql->execute();
           $destination = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
           $location = $destination['location'];

    $visit = "I want to visit $location";
```

When the php code is executed, it renders `$visit` as `"I want to visit $address"` rather than `"I want to visit 123 Magic Blvd"`. Is there a way to accomplish this? I have tried to store in sql as `"<?php $address ?>"` rather than `"$address"` but it didn't work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: really impossible to understand this question  with  out seeing the code

Comment: I just added the code. Thx.

Comment: dont store php variables in the db, that makes no sense, why are your not storing the string address "123 Magic Blvd" in the db? kind of reads lke you ware creating your own template engine?

Answer (score 0):

When you write `$visit = "I want to visit $location"`, there is no way for PHP to know that you didn't actually want to write $location as text, rather than the contents of a variable.

There are 2 options:

- Use concatentation: `$visit = "I want to visit " . $location;`
- Use string interpolation: `$visit = "I want to visit ${location}";`

*Disclaimer: I've not done PHP in years, so my syntax might not be 100% correct.*